# How do I avoid "geo:" is removed from links?

Tags: 8, navigation

I need to place on my site link with geo scheme:

```
<a href="geo:44.1234124,43.14314321432">some location</a>
```

But drupal cuts schema from link and i have following result:

```
<a href="44.1234124,43.14314321432">some location</a>
```

Is there any way to disable geo scheme filtering?

I'm using drupal 8.3.5, basic installation without any additional extensions(except autoinstalled during setup process).

UPD.
I using view that displays some fields of custom nodes as HTML list. 
Most of fields marked as "excluded from output" and for one field i'm using html output override like this:

```
<a href="geo:{{ field_somefield }}">{{ field_linktitlefield }}</a>
```

field_somefield and field_linktitlefield is a simple text.

Comment: I don't know how you are doing it but sounds like you have to mark the value/attribute as safe either via creating safemarkup object or using inline template for the render array. Again, I do not know how you are generating that link so....

Comment: Hi, @IvanJaros. Thanks for your comment. I'm added more info in my original  post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add geo as an allowed scheme. See https://blog.werk21.de/en/2017/06/06/change-list-valid-uri-schemes-drupal-8 for details.